# Resistors to be used in a circuit have average resistance 200 ohms and standard deviation 10 ohms...

Tags: probability, statistics

> Resistors to be used in a circuit have average resistance 200 ohms and standard deviation 10 ohms. Suppose 25 of these resistors are randomly selected to be used in a circuit.
>   a) What is the probability that the average resistance for the 25 resistors is between 199 and 202 ohms?
>   b) Find the probability that the total resistance does not exceed 5100 ohms.

I keep getting a negative result in part a. This follows the central limit theorem. I calculated my interval to be:

$$P((199-200)/10/(\sqrt{25}) < (X-200)/10/(\sqrt{25}) < (202-200)/10/(\sqrt{25})$$

$$P(-0.5 < Z < 1)$$

Wouldn't this be $$\Phi(1)-[1-\Phi(0.5)]?$$

Comment: $0.8413447 - (1-0.6914625)= 0.8413447-0.3085375=0.5328072\gt 0$

Comment: @Henry's comment - adding some detail: average will be 200 with std dev of 2, so 199 is 1/2 std dev below the mean and 202 is 1 std dev above. 1/2 std dev is 19.15% (from a table) and 1 std dev is 34.13% (using a table for the .13% part).

Answer (score 0):

This is not negative.

$$\Phi(1) + \Phi(0.5)-1=0.5318$$

Comment: What values are you using for your phi's?

Comment: @user108626 The values from a (standard) Normal Distribution Table.

Comment: That's what I thought! I just realized our homework gave us a different table where the shaded area is greater than Z as opposed to being less than Z on the standard normal distribution table. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user108626 And now you can do part(b) as well without problems.